# Maximum Left Positioning

Tags: javascript, css

I have an interesting question.

Is there a maximum left positioning? The reason I ask is because of a slider I am working on. Most of the layers are background images so it doesnt matter, but some are actually images (links) that slide along with the whole scene.

Right now the entire scene is ~15,000 pixels and may get larger.
Or, if you have a better way for sliding {a imgs} along the background, let me know.

Here is a link to beter help explain what I'm doing.
http://cva.ziplinestaging.com/slide/parallax.html

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Where did you find out that the max width of a website is `25,000px`? I've never heard that figure before (not that I've ever needed a `25,000px` wide webpage anyway).

Comment: A developer friend of mine was trying to build a site where all the pages on the site were to the right of the homepage. (click a nav link and it slides to another page). He told me it stopped working after 25000px. Not verified. Just from a trusty source.

Comment: Well, as you're new to [SO], please avoid speculative facts and try to back up your assertions with proof of some nature. Someone who may be a trustworthy source to you can only be hearsay to me.

Comment: You're right. I will remove that.

Comment: i will say that that is an amusing little app. You've got some minor jerkiness for some of the backgrounds, and I'm wondering if it's due to rounding errors or timing issues. Side-scrolling games typically buffer a screen-width or two on either either side of the currently active frame to avoid memory issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [this jsfiddle test](http://jsfiddle.net/DonamiteIsTNT/7ge6W/embedded/result/) I was able to move a div pretty far left. I got bored after -1,300,000px.  I'd say you have some play room.